# Angular2 filter pipe on input

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I want to add filter on the input field

```html
 <input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="_note.StudentPercent"
        ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*"
         #StudentPercent="ngForm">
```

Something like this

```
{{_note.StudentPercent| percent:'.0-0'}}
```

I also tried the following, and it doesn't work for me

```html
<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="_note.StudentPercent" 
       ngControl="StudentPercent | percent:'.0-0'" pattern="[0-9]*" 
       #StudentPercent="ngForm">

<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="_note.StudentPercent | percent:'.0-0'"
       ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*"
       #StudentPercent="ngForm">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you fail? StackOverflow is not a bunch of code monkeys ;-)

Comment: <input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text" [(ngModel)]="_note.StudentPercent" ngControl="StudentPercent | percent:'.0-0'" pattern="[0-9]*" #StudentPercent="ngForm">

<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text" [(ngModel)]="_note.StudentPercent | percent:'.0-0'" ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*" #StudentPercent="ngForm">

doesn't work for me

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: What is actually the expected behavior?

Comment: please refer  updated question I want to add a filter to input like if StudentPercent= 0.802 then it will be visible on input box like 80%

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a pipe to the model you must remove the `()` from `[(ngModel)]` and use it like `[ngModel]`.

Like so:

```html
<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text" 
   [ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent | percent:'.0-0'" 
   ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*" 
   #StudentPercent="ngForm">
```

And if you want the parameter of the pipe to be dynamic you simply do `[ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent | percent:[myDynamicParameter]"` where `myDynamicParameter` is the variable containing the value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: its not working for me
`<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text"
       [ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent| percent :_note.StudentPercent"
        ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*"
         #StudentPercent="ngForm">`

`<input class="ibox1 rightalign" type="text"
       [ngModel]="_note.StudentPercent| percent :[_note.StudentPercent]"
        ngControl="StudentPercent" pattern="[0-9]*"
         #StudentPercent="ngForm">`

Comment: Are you sure that your percent pipe is working then? Because this is the correct syntax I've provided for you. You should double check the pipe.

Comment: Yes! pipe  working fine, I used it in flex-grid-column

Comment: but the filter is not working when we update the value of the field

Comment: I would guess that is down to your pipe, since you might have programmed it in a static way. Post it as another question since this one has been resolved.